# Concept of cardinality and infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

I have seen a proof that says integers and natural numbers have the same cardinality. I understand that if we can prove there exists a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to a random set, then that set has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$.

My question is what is wrong in me thinking the following-

If I map every natural number in $\Bbb N$ to every natural number in $\Bbb Z$, it seems to me that nonnegative integers are being left out. How, then, do $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ have the same size? What implicit assumption have I made that is creating an issue?

I realize that certain functions cannot be used to prove two sets have the same size. For finite sets, if I can establish an injective function from $A$ to $B$ and there are elements in B being left out, then A and B do not have the same cardinality. This seems to not hold for infinite sets. What is the intuition behind that? How can I realize this to be true?

Comment: I'm tempted to tag your question as *philosophy* as well. Two sets having the same size means exactly there existing a bijection between the sets, **by definition**. So when you ask how you can realize that this is true, I can only interpret this as meaning there is an objective truth that we're trying to get to (this is called [Realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics#Mathematical_realism)), hence the tag *philosophy*. But if you want to ask about the **motivation** for this definition of "two sets having the same size", that seems less philosophical and clearer.

Comment: As I think you understand from your fourth paragraph, not every attempt at forming a bijection will be fruitful, and there's no logical reason to suggest that initially failing to find a bijection means that there is no bijection. Sometimes it just means that you need to look a bit harder, or be a bit more clever.

Comment: Since the idea that "a proper subset has strictly lesser cardinality" is not true in general, perhaps it's worth reading up on why it is true in the finite case?

Comment: In fact, one can define infinite sets as those which may have the same cardinality of one of its proper subsets. This definition is knows as Dedekind-infinite sets, and is equivalent to the standard definition.

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável Equivalent assuming (a very weak version of) the axiom of choice holds.

Comment: The basic concept one *must* learn is that "size" isn't about whether things have things can sometimes have left over or can be put into different looking boxes.  "size" is *entirely* about pairing items up one-to-one and *nothing else*.  So *sometimes* having numbers left over does not matter.  As for the intuition: If you have an infinite set you can always fit one more in (or one more out) without it becoming bigger or smaller... because it is infinite.  ....

Comment: ... because you can rearrange and take things out or put things into an infinite set without changing that the *are* infinite.  *SOMETIMES* having leftovers when you arrrange them one way, doesn't matter.  What matters is if you must *always* have left over and if you can or can not find a way to *avoid* having leftovers.  If you *MUST* have left overs they are different sizes.  If you *DON'T HAVE TO HAVE* left overs they are the same size.  If you *MIGHT* have leftovers is totally irrelevant.  ....

Comment: ...Okay more intuition.  We are finite sets different?  Because finite sets have a *number* of elements. If you add something to a *number* or subtract something from a *number* you get a *different* number.  But infinite sets do not have a *number* of elements.   By definition they have elements whose quantity can not be be expressed by a specific number.

Comment: So, what is the motivation behind defining two sets as having the same size if there exists a bijection mapping between them? @GitGud

Comment: @fleablood, thank you for replying (GitGud too). So, are you saying that the fact we might have leftovers and still be able to find a bijection a different wayis true because the sets are infinite? This is difficult for me to wrap my head around and I am suspecting this is because I am applying the finite concept of sets having a fixed number to these sets. (I realize this is exactly what you stated before, but could you elaborate on what it means for a set to be infinite, like the elementary properties they have that do not apply to finite sets, so I could get a clearer idea on all of this?)

Comment: I'm usually against real world examples, but here's one that I think is useful here. Consider the following scenario. You're tasked to count the number of people attending a game in a stadium. You know the stadium has, say,. $100000$ seats and you know, by inspection, that no seat is empty and no person is using more than one seat. This means that the number of people equals the number of seats, you were able to pair them. The nice thing about this way of comparing sizes is that you don't need to know the size itself and it extends naturally to infinite sets.

Comment: As an added bonus (which in fact satisfies a need), this allows us to consider different sizes of infinity.

Comment: Any bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ will prove equivalence. The embedding $\mathbb N\subseteq\mathbb Z$ is not a bijection, but that doesn't mean the sets don't have the same size.

Comment: " a fixed number"  Notice the word "number".  Infinity is not a number.  If $k$ is a number than $k + 1, k-1, etc$ are *not* equal to $k$.  That doesn't apply.

Comment: " we might have leftovers and still be able to find a bijection a different wayis true because the sets are infinite?"  Put that the other way.  Suppose you could find a bijection, does that mean you can't find a way with leftovers.  Sure you can.  Just take you bijection but instead of starting at the first element and toss it out as a leftover, now continue mapping the second one to the first one.

Comment: My guess is that the assumption you left out is that a bijection is not necessarily order preserving. And it is certainly not necessarily the identity function.

Comment: Or this one:  $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ via $n\to n$.  Obviously a bijection.  Now do $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ via $n \to n-1$.  Whoops.  $1$ is left over!.  Or $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ via $n\to n+1$.  Whoops.  We don't have enough!  Nothing goes to $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a warm-up example, it's easiest to show that there'a a bijection between the natural numbers $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and the even natural numbers $\{0,2,4,6,\ldots\}.$ This bijection takes the simple form $f(n) = 2n.$ You could make the same argument about these as you did for the integers and the naturals, since the evens are a proper subset of the naturals.

For a bijection between $\mathbb N,$  $\mathbb Z,$ simply find some orderly way to list off the integers one at a time. Like $f(0)=0, \;f(1)=1,\; f(2)=-1,\; f(3)=2,\; f(4) = -2,\ldots$

Hopefully these examples are enough to convince you that there *can* be a bijection between an infinite set and a proper subset. And the fact that the obvious inclusion that 'leaves the negative integers out' is not a bijection does not mean that no bijection exists.

As for *why* we say two sets that have a bijective correspondence have the same size, well, that's a choice we make for how to conceive of the informal notion of 'having the same size'. Basically, we just think if we can pair them off, one by one, with each element in one set corresponding to an element in another, then they have the same size. This certainly rings true in the finite case. But if we make this choice, we need to get comfortable with the fact that some properties of finite sets that have the same size do not hold for infinite sets, like that one can't be a proper subset of the other. But to say this decision to really care about bijections has been fruitful in mathematics would be an understatement.

Notice also that the notion of having a bijection is mathematically precise, whereas our decision to say 'that means they have the same size' doesn't really have any mathematical content at all, only philosophical content.

Answer (score 2):

A finite set has a specific number of elements in it.  A finite set might have $7$ elements or it might have $2,137$.  But it does have a specific number.

And if you add a few elements or take a few elements away then you get a *different* number.  This is because adding and subtracting *numbers* gives you... different numbers.

Infinite sets do *not* have any specific number of elements in it.  Adding or subtracting a few elements will not change how many elements you have.  You can even remove every other element (thus remove an infinite number) and still have an infinite number.  (Remove all odds from all the integers you are still left with all the evens).

So because you can always add or subtract and not change size, you can always find some way to rearrange infinite things so that you have left overs.  Or you can rearrange so you dont "have enough".  So the possibility of *maybe* having leftovers or *maybe* not having enough, can't and doesn't actually matter when it comes to cardinality.

What *does* matter is if you *HAVE* to have left overs.  Or if you will *never* have enough.  It doesn't matter if you *might* have leftovers but if you *HAVE TO* have left overs and can't avoid, then they are not the same size.

And if you *CAN* have it work out evenly and avoid leftovers or find a way so that you have "just enough", if that is *possible* (not *every* time but if it possible to sometimes have it perfectly even) then we say they are the same "size".  Well, we don't.  We say they are the same cardinality.  As "size" is misleading and actually meaningless now.

Foe example $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$ via, if $x > 0$ then $x\to x$ will have "leftovers".  None of the negatives are mapped.  But that's fine.  That's just *one* way of doing it.

We could have done. $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$ via, if $x <0$ then $x\mapsto 2^{|x|}$ and if $x \ge 0$ then $x\mapsto 3^x$.  Then we don't have any leftovers.  We have the opposite problem.  We don't have enough! we only mapped to the powers of $2$ and $3$.  No other primes and no other composites get mapped to at all.

But that doesn't matter.  That was only *one* way of doing it.  We can also do.  If $x \le 0$ them $x\mapsto 2|x|+1$ and $x > 0$ then $x\mapsto 2x$.  That *is* one to one and we have no left overs and they all fit.  That we *could* do that is what matters.  That there were other unsuccessful ways does not.

Another example:  $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$.  If we come up with an injective map (so that no two integers map to the same real number) then we will *never* have leftovers and we will *never* have enough.  And we can never do it evenly.  So they are different cardinalities.